# DisplayLink Driver Issue on Manjaro

Tags: manjaro

I’m reaching out to this forum because I’m facing an issue with my Manjaro system. Specifically, I’ve been struggling to get the DisplayLink driver to work properly. I’ve scoured through various forums and tried different solutions, but unfortunately, nothing seems to be working.

Despite my efforts, I still can’t seem to resolve the problem. So, I’m turning to this community for some assistance.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem, I would greatly appreciate your help. I’m open to trying out any suggestions or troubleshooting steps you may have.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Best regards

```
yay -S displaylink evdi-git
```

```
systemctl status displaylink.service
● displaylink.service - DisplayLink Manager Service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/displaylink.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-02-11 12:32:21 CET; 1s ago
Process: 37582 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe evdi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 1ms
```

```
journalctl -xeu displaylink.service

A start job for unit displaylink.service has begun execution.

 The job identifier is 31972.
Feb 11 12:33:46 rootware modprobe[37744]: modprobe: FATAL: Module evdi not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.13-7-MANJARO
Feb 11 12:33:46 rootware systemd[1]: displaylink.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/help-needed-cannot-install-displaylink-drivers/124987

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/noob-manjaro-user-with-displaylink-problems/114773